# AC current limiting for testing an AC circuit

Tags: ac, test-equipment

I am planning to test an AC circuit which I am repairing (the circuit has a short). I want to slowly bring the power up to identify which component is shorting.

I purchased a Variac, so that I can slowly increase the voltage, but I’m told that while useful, this may not actually limit the current.

As an aside, I also purchased an isolation transformer to use in series before the Variac, as a safety measure.

For current limiting, it seems that a popular approach is to use a 60 W bulb in series with the test circuit. I’m happy to try this and it sounds logical, but is it the best way? Why is this the common approach? Could a resistor achieve the same result? Is there bench equipment designed for this purpose?

Comment: a resistor would also work, i often use a 100W ceramic potentiometer. They are more linear than a dim bulb, which is sometimes handy/important, but you can also use both in series as long as the pot allows enough current to heat the filament.

Comment: @dandavis I have a pretty beefy rheostat, that’s the same thing, right?

Comment: I'd always wondered what that term meant. My grandpa used it to describe lamp dimmers. Yes, it's the same thing as a pot. Supposedly a pot is a voltage divider and a rheostat isn't, but all the images i can find show terminals on both ends of the rheostat and on it's wiper, so I don't really see a difference and besides, you only need 2 terminals in this application anyway. Also, you might want to consider an inline fuse or resettable circuit breaker, just in case of earthquakes or poor momentary judgment.

Comment: Or if I experience involuntary movements… I have a twitch in my right index finger that seems to begin when family members enter my workshop.

Comment: A high wattage resistor can be used, but  there are two things to be said in favor of incandescent light bulbs. 1) incandescent light bulbs are cheap, 2) when they are on, the light warns you that they are on.

Comment: I definitely see the value of the visual warning.

Comment: @dandavis I noticed something. When you search for "rheostat" you tend to get pots that can handle > 10 W; I suppose because they're designed to limit more current than a regular pot.

Comment: I just realised though, is there any point in using a pot if I'm using a Variac? Both seem to achieve the same result; a voltage and current drop.

Comment: @NickBolton think of it as a lab power supply able to control voltage and limit current. Most of the time you don't need constant current, but boy howdy, is it ever nice to have when you do. If you drive non-ohmic loads like LEDs, or if you have a short, then that resistance is indispensable and doesn't much get in that way when not needed.

Comment: Hmm, yes very true. If I have a 60 W bulb, does the pot need to be able to dissipate the same power, or does the bulb cause a voltage drop to the point that the power running through the pot is much lower? Relative to ground, the potential depends on the resistance caused by the pot, right? Ran this through a circuit sim and couldn’t quite figure it out. I only have a 1W pot in my inventory with high (5k) resistance, so I’m thinking I’ll need something much bigger. The “beefy rheostat” I mentioned is high power but low resistance (too low to be useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 60 W bulb is cheap, designed to handle line voltage and has readily available holders.  It also has a non-linear resistance characteristic, so your circuit can pull a few mA of current without much voltage drop but if there's a short you weren't expecting, it will rapidly increase resistance and limit current to whatever 60 W is for your line voltage (and give you a very obvious indication).  Are there better ways of applying power to your device?  Without knowing your circuit and its probable/possible failure modes, there's no way to know for sure.  I do suggest an alternate diagnostic method though as variacs won't provide galvanic isolation and finding a short should be fairly easy in a disconnected circuit.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.

Comment: And if 60W doesn't equate to the current limit you want, then a wide variety of other wattages are available.

Comment: @SimonB Lower the bulb W for more current limiting, yes? I noticed many people have a 2 bulb in parallel design... perhaps this is to fine tune the limit? Or maybe to add redundancy in case one blows?

Answer (score 0):

In case it's of use to anyone, here's a schematic I came up with...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMoJC7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note: Instead of an ammeter, I'd actually use a precision CT sensor.

And here's [Mr Carlson's](https://youtu.be/51mjt9nFoeA?t=986) dim bulb tester schematic...

[image: Mr Carlson's schematic]

Notice how he puts his isolator after the Variac. Paul Scherz (page 388 of Practical Electronics for Inventors) actually advises that you place the isolation before the Variac, and never after.

> It is important to note that a Variac by itself does not provide isolation protection like a standard transformer, since the primary and secondary shared a common winding. It is therefore important, if you plan to work on ungrounded, "hot chassis" equipment, that you **place an isolation transformer before the Variac—never after it**. If you don't shock hazards await.